# standard matrix using a orthonormal bases

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I need a small clarification. I was trying to solve the following question. 
If $u_1,u_2,....,u_n $ and $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ are orthonormal  bases for  $\mathbb{R}^n$. construct the matrix A that transforms each $v_j$ into $u_j$ to give $Av_1=u_1,.... Av_n=u_n.$

So clearly A is an $n*n$ matrix, and $A[v_1 v_2 .. v_n] = [u_1 u_2 ... u_n]$.  I don't know how to proceed after that..I think , each $v_j$ is a combination of $ T(u_j)'s $ then using the dot product to find the coefficients. Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $A\left[ v_1\;v_2\;\dots\;v_n\right]=\left[ u_1\;u_2\;\dots\;u_n\right]$

Comment: So A is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $u_1/v_1, u_2/v_2,... u_n/v_n$ Am I right?

Comment: $u_i/v_i$ is not even defined, note that these are vectors. Given this matrix equation, you can use the fact that for a matrix $V$ with orthonormal columns, $VV^T=V^TV=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: You should first specify the base(s) of $\mathbb{R}^n$ relevant to set up the matrix.

Comment: Then, If both orthonormal bases are the standard bases, then A is the identity matrix.

Comment: @user142807 Two standard basis?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mean ${v_1  v_2 .. v_n}$ orthonormal bases for input space, and ${u_1 u_2 .... u_n}$ - orthonormal bases for output space.

Comment: The matrix A is $[u_1 u_2 ... u_n].[v_1 v_2 ... v_n]^T$. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @user142807 Well, what you wrote is one single number...I suppose you meant exactly the other way: $$(u_1...u_n)^t(v_1,...v_n)$$

Comment: I mean my matrix A is given by $U.V^T$. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks all for your replies! appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Convince yourself that if $\;\{w_1,..,w_n\}\;$ is *any* orthonormal basis, then for any $\;v\in V\;$ we have the easy expression

$$v=\sum_{k=1}^n \langle\,v\,,\,w_k\,\rangle\,w_k$$

Thus, in our case we have that

$$\forall\;1\le i\le n\;,\;\;v_i=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle\,v_i\,,\,u_k\,\rangle\,u_k\implies$$

$$ A=\left(\langle\,v_i\,,\,u_j\rangle\right)_{1\le i,j\le n}=\begin{pmatrix}\langle v_1,u_1\rangle&\langle v_1,u_2\rangle&\ldots&\langle v_1,u_n\rangle\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\\langle v_n,u_1\rangle&\langle v_n,u_2\rangle&\ldots&\langle v_n,u_n\rangle\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: one clarification.. suppose  ${(v_1,v_2...v_n)}$, is an  orthonormal bases for the input space V, then each $v_i$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the bases vectors. and all the coefficients are zero because of linear independence property. Am I right?

Comment: Of course, **but not** all coefficients: for any $\;i\;$ , $\;v_i=0\cdot v_1+\ldots+\color{red}1\cdot v_i+\ldots+0\cdot v_n\;$